# Cross compiling for Raspberry pi 2 error

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi2

I wanted to start cross compiling for raspberry pi2 on Ubuntu 32bit (in virtual box), so I downloaded the toolchain on the github site (https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools) and tried to compile a simple hello world program with the command (I've included the path to the bin folder that contains arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3 to the PATH variable.):

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3 HelloWorld.c
```

However, I always get the following error message:

```
path/to/the/linker/in/the/toolchain/ld:/path/to/the/libc.so.6file/in/the/toolchain/libc.so.6: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
```

and subsequently a syntax error.
When I look into libc.so.6, I see a single line containing:

```
libc-2.13.so
```

The libc-2.13.so file is present in the same folder as the libc.so.6 file. When I invoke

```
file libc-2.13.so
```

I get:

```
libc-2.13.so: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), BuildID[sha1]=dbd0cdca5a677bea1417be1272f4c5ef43bd3e22, for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, stripped
```

I don't know what could cause this error since obviously the linker from the toolchain and the libc.so.6 file from the toolchain are processed so the file format should be recognized, right?
Can someone point me in the right direction here? Thanks!

Comment: I think you're missing the link path, so the linker tries to link your system's libc instead of toolchains. Try add `-L` option to specify the toolchain's libraries.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your comment! I've tried the -I and -L flags to the appropriate locations of the toolchain (libc/lib and include) and still got the same error... However since I included the toolchain as the first location in PATH, it already took the correct libc.so file (the path to the libc file is also included in the error message) Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: Compile with the -v option to see the actual linker command being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest you alternate way to do Cross compilation. I tried it and it works. You can use [crosstool-NG](http://crosstool-ng.org/). It gives you graphical way to setup your toolchain for cross compilation. There are lot of option for setting up toolchain. You can explore that.

Now you are doing for **ARM-RPi** but tomorrow if your Target CPU changed then it will be very easy to reconfigure the toolchain again.

You can find easy steps given in [this article](http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/426). I hope this works for you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Shadwell : I am new to this Forum. I edited my answer. Can you please tell me, Is that fine ?

Comment: @Amol it would be perhaps more convenient to use [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) from the very beginnig. BR already provides RPi2 target.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer, but it hoped I would get around building the toolchain by myself by using the ones that are provided on github. I even tried this method with crosstool-NG (by following another tutorial) before but got the error:

    "[ERROR]  Missing: 'i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++' or 'i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++' or 'g++' : either needed!"

when performing: "ct-ng build" Anyway, I will try the tutorial that you provided and report back! Thanks again!

Comment: @yegorich : yeah I agree **Buildroot** is good option. If anyone interested then can follow below link : https://github.com/gamaral/rpi-buildroot

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions, doing it with buildroot worked in the end!

Answer (score 2):

> When I look into libc.so.6, I see a single line containing:
>   libc-2.13.so

I just ran into this.
The problem is way simpler than you think.  When you un-gz'd and untar'd the toolchain, what happened is that libc.so.6 became a text file.  It is supposed to be a "symbolic link" file pointing at the correct file "libc-2.13.so".

If you are using windows and 7-Zip, make sure to click "Run AS Administrator" when you start 7-zip.   If you simply drag and drop, the error is not so obvious.

Answer (score 1):

In my first effort, I had to include the path to gcc in the command. Then I just compiled programs on the RPi.

```
  ~/toolchain/raspbian-toolchain-gcc-4.7.2-linux32/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc whets.c
```

Comment: Hi! I tried to provide absolute paths when compiling (I also tried it with absolute path within the -I and -L flag) but still: the same error ... but thanks for your answer anyway!